# UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout section content insets bug

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I'm noticing a buggy behaviour for the `UICollectionViewCompositional` layout when dealing with big content insets inside orthogonal sections.

Consider this simple layout

```swift
let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(200), heightDimension: .absolute(200))
let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
let section: NSCollectionLayoutSection = .init(group: group)
section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuous
section.contentInsets = .init(top: 0, leading: 200, bottom: 0, trailing: 0)
section.interGroupSpacing = 10
```

Notice that:

- the group width is `.absolute(200)`
- the section leading content inset is 200

The problem is that **when the leading section content inset is equal or greater than the group width** (200 in this case), **the last cells in the section disappear** (see the table below).
This behaviour appears to be the same in iOS 13.7, 14.4 and 14.5. I didn't test other versions.

| **section.contentInsets.leading < 200** ✅ | **section.contentInsets.leading >= 200** ❌ |
| --- | --- |
| The last cell (number 5) is correctly visible | The last cell (number 5) disappeared leaving a blank space |
| [image: The last cell (5) is correctly visible] | [image: The last cell (5) disappeared leaving a blank space] |

What do you think?
Am I doing something wrong here or it could be something to be reported to Apple?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was a bug in UIKit.
The same app works correctly on iOS 15 beta and Xcode 13.